# Google map coordinates info window on click

Tags: google-maps

Does anyone know how make the default Google map interface display long and lat coordinates in an info window when the user clicks on the map?

Header code:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=..." type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(13.175771, -59.556885), 10);
    map.setUIToDefault();
  }
}
</script>
```

Body code:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 640px; height: 300px"></div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      position: event.latLng,
      content: event.latLng.toString() 
    }).open(map);
 });
```

Comment: Jonathan, thanks, but not sure where to use that. Should I add that function to the header Javascript?

Comment: I've edited my original question to include my header and body code.

Comment: Do you really need use the deprecated version 2 of the api? I've given you code for v3, which is the current version.

Comment: If you're interested, you have helped me add a neat little map coordinate getter to the end of this form: http://www.barbadosphonebook.com/list-your-business-for-free/

Comment: Ask another question about that :D. And put the link in these comments, I'll come and answer it.

Comment: Thanks. Will do that soon; once I scoop-up the details for the question.

Comment: Hey Sudhir Jonathan, here's the question for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953659/how-do-i-use-google-map-data-in-other-form-elements