# How to get the GPS coordinates after clicking on the Google map embedded in the Qt widget?

Tags: qt, google-maps, gps, mouseevent

I have already found the ways to embed the Google maps in the Qt widgets.

Now the next task is to get the GPS coordinates when I click on the map image in the Qt widget.

I looked up this thread: [Google map coordinates info window on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840175/google-map-coordinates-info-window-on-click)

The solution shown there is in Javascript.

I am working in Qt. So, I looked up this: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2.0-beta1/qgeosearchmanager.html

Does **QGeoSearchManager** api produce the GPS coordinates of the location where the mouse clicked on the widget (containing the map)? I couldn't find, how?

Found these link: Will they be helpful in a way?

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2.0-beta1/qml-position.html

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2.0-beta1/qml-positionsource.html

Comment: This depends on how you've implemented Google Maps into you QWidget.It'll help if you can provide an explanation on how you did the same.

Comment: @Abhijith  I haven't implemented anything till now, but found the ways to do it. See this link: http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Fetching_a_map_tile_in_Qt_using_Google_Maps

Comment: That is just a very basic implementation. It only fetches and displays a tile only when you know the lat and long position. To calculate what point has been clicked you need to map pixels to real geographical distance and then calculate the lat and long.

Comment: For example - for a given zoom level , 10 pixels on screen might equal 1 degree shift in latitude etc .. You would also take into consideration the direction from the original known point .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had put the same question on the QtCentre foras, and the people there gave me a link to the Qt class named "***[QGraphicsGeoMap](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2.0-beta1/qgraphicsgeomap.html)***". The function there titled "***screenPositionToCoordinate***" looks promising.